Unable to run debugger on WSL on Ubuntu (VS Code), Windows 11
I'm trying to debug Python code written in venv environment I created.
These are the debugging steps:
On VS Code > Run and Debug (clicking the play icon on side bar or pressing ctrl + shift + D) > click 'create a launch.json file' > select Python environment  and script to debug
When trying these steps, it opens a new window, in powershell, instead of bash. Also, the window is no longer in WSL mode, and the venv. Therefore the debugger seems unable to read venv dependencies, and so, could not complete.
I have checked out the VS Code knowledge base, Python Debugging in VS Code, and tried to run the debugger on command line instead. I installed debugpy, and ran python3 -m debugpy --listen 5678 q_learning.py . It just ran the program, without the debugging process (shown).
Could someone tell what goes wrong here? How could i resolve this?
